# config nginx to serve vuejs app on subdomain listening on 443

Tags: nginx

I want to run vuejs app on `sub.domain.com`, and I simply configure nginx like bellow:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen 443;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.key;

   server_name sub.domain.com;
   charset utf-8;
   root    /var/www/xxx/dist;
   index   index.html index.htm;

   location / {
      root /var/www/xxx/dist;
      try_files $uri /index.html;
   }
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/xxx-error.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/xxx-access.log;
}
```

but when I apply this configuration, the vuejs app loads on main domain (`domain.com`) and breaks the website. I can not understand what is wrong here!
and also when I remove the lines related to ssl, all is good and it works as I expect on http

Comment: The obvious error is `ssl on;` which should be removed and use: `listen 80; listen 443 ssl;` instead. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server).

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks for answer, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -T`.